# Telegraf Using a listener to process POST with JSON data

Tags: http, post, influxdb, telegraf

I would like to use the tick stack for timeseries data.

I have seen that the `inputs.http_listener` only accepts the influxDB line-protocol.

Is there a way to send data via HTTP POST with data in a JSON format with a listener running on telegraf?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `[[intputs.socket_listener]]` specifying `data_format = "json"`.

```
 [[inputs.socket_listener]]   
   service_address = "tcp://127.0.0.1:http"
   # service_address = "tcp://:8094"
   # service_address = "udp://:8094"

   max_connections = 1024
   read_timeout = "30s" 
   data_format = "json"
```

Though, I am not sure, whether this will react to HTTP POST.

[Telegraf data formats](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md) 
[Socket listener](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/socket_listener)